# App stopping when Play Store version downloaded, but same version works perfectly when build variant run directly on phone

Tags: android

I recently attempted to update my app on the Play Store. The previous version was working perfectly, and previous updates have been fine too. I trialled the new version as a debug variant, and then again as a build variant running it directly to my phone. It was working fine then, yet when I generate a signed APK and release it to the Play Store, it opens the main screen but is stopping the moment I click on a button.

I'm getting an error:

```
Process: com.creation.elfho.ncearesultstracker, PID: 1753
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method onClick(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.widget.LinearLayout
        at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(View.java:5089)
        at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:5048)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6261)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23748)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

My only guess is that something may have happened when I updated Android Studio just recently (since the last time I updated the app).

I'll put my gradle code here too as I guess that's the most likely place for there to be an error:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.creation.elfho.ncearesultstracker"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 7
    versionName "3.4"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
```

Any ideas about what I may have done?

Comment: Sometimes when you go to publish, the App Store will tell you that you need to upgrade certain version or libraries.  Did this happen to you, and did you change any versions last minute?

Comment: No this didn't happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens sometimes where some classes / methods are not dexed & therefore not shipped in the app leading to a crash...
Your best bet would be to Clean/Rebuild the Project > Build Production Apk > Test if it works!

Also try removing 'proguard' from `release { ... }` in `build.gradle`.

Comment: The clean/rebuild fixed it! Thank you so much I was just about tearing my hair out!

Comment: @Roonil happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing involved with the play store here.  Somewhere you have an onClick defined where you either don't have a matching function on that Activity, you typoed the name, or you have the wrong signature.

Comment: I definitely have a matching function with a correctly spelled name, there's only one onClick for this activity. What do you mean have the wrong signature?

Comment: Wrong function signature.  For example, you forgot that it needs to take a View as a parameter.  Or you had it return something other than void.  Or it wasn't public.  The correct signature for an onClick is     public void myfunction(View view)

Comment: I've done none of those things. Why is it working perfectly in my debug variant but not when released?

Comment: Then its probably a proguard rule only run on release that's renaming the function.  Turn off proguard and try again.  The error is 100% that it can't find that specially named funciton.

Comment: Isn't it already turned off in my gradle? minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

Comment: No, its usually turned off for dev and on for release.  Which is exactly what you're describing.  You're listing two proguard rule files there that will be run.  You're just not minifying (removing unused functions)

Comment: Ok. How do I turn it off?